# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' with two DataSources in context.xml

Tags: java, mysql, authentication, sqlexception, context.xml

I'm facing a problem with Java 8, MySQL Server 5.7.23, MySQL Connector for Java v5.1.45 and Tomcat v9.0.12 (running on Ubuntu Server 18.04).

I've built a simple Java application (war) that executes a query in a MySQL database.

My context.xml (I've put 2 resources nodes, one for production and one for developing environment), from the real application scenario I read from CATALINA_OPTS a parameter called "env" and reading it with System.getProperty("env"), the application can choose the appropriate datasource to use.

```
<Context>
    <!-- MySQL - Production -->
    <Resource
        name="prod-jdbc/ds-1" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?useSSL=false"
        username="dbuser" password="dbUserPwd!"
        autoReconnect="true" maxTotal="10"
        minIdle="3" maxIdle="5" maxActive="10" maxWaitMillis="10000"
        removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true" removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true"
        logAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="1000"
        closeMethod="close" testOnBorrow="true"
        testWhileIdle="true" timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="60000"
        validationQueryTimeout="10" validationInterval="6000"
        validationQuery="SELECT 1"
    />

    <!-- MySQL - Development -->
    <Resource
        name="dev-jdbc/ds-1" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/localdb?useSSL=false"
        username="root" password="root"
        autoReconnect="true" maxTotal="10"
        minIdle="3" maxIdle="5" maxActive="10"
        maxWaitMillis="10000" removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true"
        removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true" logAbandoned="true"
        removeAbandonedTimeout="1000" closeMethod="close"
        testOnBorrow="true" testWhileIdle="true"
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="60000" validationQueryTimeout="10"
        validationInterval="6000" validationQuery="SELECT 1"
    />
</Context>
```

A simple tester class:

```
package main;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

public class ConnectionTester extends Application implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        Context ctx = null; Connection con = null; Statement stmt = null; ResultSet rs = null;
        try{
            ctx = new InitialContext();
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/prod-jdbc/ds-1");
            con = ds.getConnection();
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT nome FROM Customers");
            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
            }
        }
        catch(NamingException | SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally{
            try {
                rs.close(); stmt.close(); con.close(); ctx.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception in closing DB resources");
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception in closing Context");
            }
        }
    } // contextInitialized
} // ConnectionTester
```

I've set MySQL permission this way (I also need to allow external access for "dbuser" because I have an external client that connects to this MySQL database):

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'veryStrongPwd';
CREATE USER 'dbuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'dbUserPwd!';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'dbuser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'dbuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'dbUserPwd!' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Tomcat doesn't have any specific configuration or resource configured, it's simply the v9.0.12 unzipped in a folder.

I've tried to put in context.xml both the "root" and the "dbuser" credentials but when I start Tomcat, I get the following problem:

```
ConnectionPool.init Unable to create initial connections of pool.
 java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:873)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1710)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226)
...
```

And after throwing those exeptions, it prints the recordset, but why does it require the root login even if in the context.xml I set dbuser credentials?

I've read searched here in StackOverflow and I've read that I've to check the mysql.user table, if I run:

```
SELECT user, host, plugin, authentication_string FROM mysql.user;
```

I get this ("plugin" column has "mysql_native_password" value for every record):

[image]

If I try to login into MySQL server from the shell with:

```
mysql -u root (or dbuser) -p
```

I can login succesfully.

EDIT: I've found that deleting the second "Resource" node from context.xml (the one made for development environment), the problem disappears, but I still don't uderstand why it happens because in the lookup I choose the prod resource (ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/prod-jdbc/ds-1")).

What am I missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a comment on security. You don't need to allow dbuser from everywhere, if the only user connecting  is your app that is hosted in localhost or at your server ip.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I agree with you but I also have an external application that has to connect to this Java server (I didn't write that in the question) ;)

Comment: Stupid question:Have you confirmed that the context.xml which is being used by Tomcat is getting refreshed with your  context.xml ?? Sometimes based on the configuration settings it might not pick up the latest context.xml, so even if you make changes it might not reflect.

Comment: @rohitthomas The context.xml contained in WAR archive is the same that I find in the application unpacked folder once the Tomcat is started. I've updated the question with some new informations that I've discovered when I was looking at context.xml (see EDIT at bottom). Thanks for the answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

In your `context.xml` you have the `root` user password as `root`. In your MySQL script, you've set the `root` user password to `veryStrongPwd`.

If your question is more about why you get the error even though you don't use the `Resource` - you're  setting the minimum size of the connection pool to `3`. So Tomcat will create the connection pool, and try to add 3 connections to it at startup. Perhaps if you set `minIdle` to `0` it would work how you want it to.

**UPDATE**

There's another setting - `initialSize` which defaults to 10. Setting that to 0 should stop Tomcat trying to use that DataSource at startup.

Comment: This is exactly it. +10. There are two connection pools in context.xml.  The second pool (below `<!-- MySQL - Development -->`)  ... specifies credentials for root user. This is what is causing the exceptions to be thrown, when tomcat starts, its attempting to start three connections, to initialize the connection pool with `minIdle` connections.

Comment: Yes, the point is that I didn't understand why it initializes the "development" datasource even if it is not used from Java source. I've understood your answer, so I've edited context.xml setting minIdle to "0" for both the datasources but the Exception at runtime still remains :( Any ideas? Thanks for your answer, I've put +1 on both :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the permission [IP] from the client that you use to connect. Sometimes need to be specific when you create a new cliente that connect from another terminal when is not a localhost.

Comment: Tomcat is on the same machine of the MySQL server so the client address is localhost and "dbuser" have privileges on localhost (see screenshot on first post).